# Min and max directives not working as expected in Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, frontend

Greetings developers around of the world,

I am trying to deeply understand how to use the "min" and "max" directives in Angular 6, I am aware of the unsupported functionality changes before the Angular 2 version, but now I am using the version 6, so it is supposed to not cause trouble.

However, I was expecting, with the "max" validator, stopping the user of typing more than 9999, Instead of this behaviour, I am only triggering the Validator but not stoping the user, allowing them to type infinite numbers.

How can I achieve this classical "maxlength" behaviour but with an input of type number?

**EDIT**

I am using PrimeNG components

```
<input class="ss" type="text" [formControl]="numPolizaCtrl" [(ngModel)]="conceptoForm.numPoliza" pInputText pKeyFilter="pint" placeholder="Nº póliza">

<label *ngIf="numPolizaCtrl.invalid" [ngClass] = "'error'" > Too much numbers. </label>

numPolizaCtrl = new FormControl("", [Validators.max(9999999999), Validators.min(0)]);
```

I want to stop the user of typing more than "x" number of characters, the same behaviour as the maxLength directive but using an input of type "number".

Thank you all.

Comment: Please show us the relevant markup/code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @ConnorsFan, the question is now updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not use `maxlength` in `input:number` you use `min` and `max` or use this solution:

in your HTMLTemplete

```
 <input id="txtNumber" placeholder="4 character only" (keydown)="isNumberKey($event)"   
        type="text" name="txtNumber" maxlength="4">
```

and in your component

```
isNumberKey(evt)
        {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                  return false;
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I am asking for... I am alredy using validators to trigger a true or false validation like you did in your "isNumberKey()" method, the problem is that I don't know how to stop the user of **TYPING** more than 10 numbers in the input. Thank you @puntanet

Comment: if you use maxlength="10" the user can put a maximum of 10 digits

Comment: Wow man, I tried that like 5 times and it was not working but I tried one more time and now works, yeah! Thx man. So the answer is to use maxlength and minlenght for limiting the user for typing more and use the validators of "min" and "max" for code logic.

Answer (score 2):

Try using regular expressions:

HTML:

```
<input class="ss" type="text" [formControl]="numPolizaCtrl" [(ngModel)]="conceptoForm.numPoliza" pInputText pKeyFilter="pint" placeholder="Nº póliza"(keydown)=validateNumber($event)>
```

End your component:

```
  validateNumber(event: KeyboardEvent) {     
    let regEx =  new RegExp('^[0-9]*$');

    if(regEx.test(event.key) || event.key=="Backspace" )
         return true;
    else
         return false;
 }
```